# calling stored proc from stored proc with table-valued parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure (sp_A) that receives data through a table-valued parameter (tvp), inserts all records into a table (table_A), and then makes a call to another stored procedure (sp_B). sp_B receives input parameters from some of the columns in the tvp, and has one output parameter @return of type nvarchar. Executing sp_B with a single row of input parameters works just fine. The problem is in calling sp_B from sp_A with a tvp, because then sp_B returns more than one value, which I'd like to handle, but can't find a suitable data structure to hold all the return values.

I have here a semblance of the problematic query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_A]       
@return varchar(50) output,
@inputData inputTable readonly    
AS    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION       
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;       
    declare @typeid int, @insertcount int       
    set @typeid = (select typeid from @inputData ) 

    --if typeid is not provided, insert into table_A and exit stored proc
    if(@typeid IS NULL OR @typeid = 0)             
        BEGIN          
          INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]                  
             [cola1], [cola2], [cola3])       
          select _cola1, _cola2, _cola3     
             from @inputData
          set @insertcount = @@ROWCOUNT          
          set @return = 'successful'     
        END

    --else if typeid is provided, insert into table_A, and call sp_B, passing input parameters from @inputData

    ELSE
        BEGIN
          declare @colb1 varchar, @colb2 varchar, @colb3 varchar            
          INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]                          
            ([cola1], [cola2], [cola3], [typeid ])                  
          select _cola1, _cola2, _cola3, _typeid                  
            from @inputData

          select @colb1 = _colb1, @colb2 = _colb2, @colb3 = _colb3    
            from @moTable
          exec @insertcount = sp_B
            @colb1, @colb2, @colb3, @return output

        END    
COMMIT TRANSACTION
select @insertcount 
RETURN
```

I'm getting a "subquery returns more than 1 value..." error, understandably so... but I need that full value set for further processing in the application. What would be the best way to return, handle and propagate the return value set to the calling program (C# in this case)?

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: Please format your SQL  if you want an answer

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: Can **you** read that sql code?

Comment: If you are 100000% certain that every single row will always contain the same value for typeid in every single row you could simply use top 1. If the values can change per row then you need a different approach to handle each row type individually.

Comment: The question is too broad to be able to adequately answer the question on this forum. As @ZoharPeled has stated, read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. One question, can you edit Stored Procedure B?

Comment: @SeanLange the issue is with the return value, and the output parameter (@insertcount, and @return). They return more than one value since there are multiple tvp records passed to the stored proc (sp_B). If tvp's could be used as output, it'd solve the problem. I can't find a workaround, and I need to handle each return value separately for every row of input data passed to sp_B